# Gyroscopic Effect at non-90 degree offsets

Tags: rotational-kinematics, gyroscopes

So I’m well aware of the way that the gyroscopic effect is normally described, that a torque applied to a rotating object will take effect 90 degrees later on the rotation (forgive me if I’m misusing terms here), but just recently one thing confused me. What if the rotation speed is really slow?

What I mean is if we have a non-rotating wheel then it will behave as expected and turn in the directing that we apply a torque. And if we have a wheel spinning very fast then it will behave in accordance with the gyroscopic effect and rotate 90 degrees away from our applied torque. But what about a very slowly rotating wheel?

Intuition tells me that it would behave like the non-rotating wheel, but since it is in fact rotating maybe it would behave like the fast wheel.

The third and most probably option is that it would be in between the two and the torque would take effect between 0 and 90 degrees away, like 45, but I have never ever seen any equation describing this so I’m skeptical. If it is this option could you please include the equation because I would be very interested to see what situations would give rise to offsets like 20 or 30 degrees.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If the applied torque about the CG is ${\bf M}$ and the angular momentum about the CG is ${\bf H}$, then the equation you want to stare at for a while is the balance of angular momentum: ${\bf M} = \dot{{\bf H}}$.

So if ${\bf H} = {\bf 0}$ initially, and then you apply ${\bf M}$, then ${\bf H}$ will grow in the direction of ${\bf M}$.

If ${\bf H}$ is large initially, and you apply a torque ${\bf M}$ perpendicular to ${\bf H}$ then it will work predominantly to steer ${\bf H}$, and swivel it around in a circle.

In between these two extreme cases lies the scenario you are speaking of, where ${\bf M}$ would do a combination of changing the direction of ${\bf H}$ as well as its magnitude.

I recommend you draw out the vector geometry/calculus for the cases you already understand, see how ${\bf H}$ is supposed to change, and then move on to your hypotheticals. Maybe get a bike tire and do some experiments. Let me know what you discover.